# counter to check if array X is subsequence of A not working (C)

Tags: c, if-statement, sequence, binary-search

I've tried following this program by hand, but I still can't get it to work.

I have an array `A = [4,3,2,1,4,3,2,1,4,3,2,1,4,3,2,1,4,3,2,1]` and array `X = [1,2,3]`.
I need to find the max number `i` for `X^i` that is a subsequence of `A`, and do this by binary search.

Since size of `A` is 20, and size of `X` is 3, the max possible `i = 20/3 = 6`. So my search will start at `i = 3`, which means that `X^3 = [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3]`.
This is not a subsequence of `A`, so binary search repeats for `i = 1, X^1 = [1,2,3]`.
This is a subsequence of A, meaning it should pass and binary search should try again for `i = 2`.

**However, my condition to see if the iteration passes or not is not working properly.**

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void create_initial_arrays(int size_a, int *A, int size_x, int *X);
void binary_search(int size_a, int * A, int size_x, int *X, int max_i, int min_i);

int main(){


    int size_a, size_x;
    scanf("%d", &size_a);
    scanf("%d", &size_x);

    int max_i = size_a / size_x;
    int min_i = 0;

    printf("Max: %d\n", max_i);

    int *A = (int*) malloc(size_a *sizeof(int));
    int *X = (int*) malloc(size_x *sizeof(int));

    create_initial_arrays(size_a, A, size_x, X);

    printf("Old X: ");
    for(int i = 0; i < size_x; i++){
        printf("%d ", X[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    binary_search(size_a, A, size_x, X, max_i, min_i);
    free(X);
    free(A);

}

void create_initial_arrays(int size_a, int *A, int size_x, int *X){
    int i, throwaway;

    for(i = 0; i < size_a; i++){
        scanf("%d", &A[i]);
    }

    scanf("%d", &throwaway);

    for(i = 0; i < size_x; i++){
        scanf("%d", &X[i]);
    }

    scanf("%d", &throwaway);
}



void binary_search(int size_a, int * A, int size_x, int *X, int max_i, int min_i){

    int j, k, max_repeat = 0;

    while(min_i <= max_i){

        int i = 0, count = 0, repeats = (max_i + min_i)/2;

        printf("\n");
        int * temp = (int*) malloc(size_x * sizeof(int) * repeats);

        for(k = 0; k < size_x; ++k){
            for(j = 0; j < repeats; ++j){
                temp[k * repeats + j] = X[k];
            }
        }

        printf("New X: ");
            for(i = 0; i < size_x * repeats; i++){
                printf("%d ", temp[i]);
            }

        printf("A: ");
        for (i = 0; i < size_a; i++){
            printf("%d ", A[i]);
        }

        for(j = 0; j < size_a; j++){
            if(A[j] == temp[i]){
                count++;
                i++;
            }
        }



        printf("Count: %d", count);


        if (count >= size_x * repeats){
            printf("Low: %d Mid %d High % d Passes\n", min_i, repeats, max_i);
            min_i = repeats + 1;
            max_repeat++;
        }
        else{
            printf("Low: %d Mid %d High % d Fails\n", min_i, repeats, max_i);
            max_i = repeats - 1;
        }

        free(temp);
    }   
        printf("Max repeat: %d", max_repeat);
}
```

And this is the section that I think must be problematic:

```
for(j = 0; j < size_a; j++){
            if(A[j] == temp[i]){
                count++;
                i++;
            }
        }
```

I've output both Arrays to make sure they are populated correctly (they are) and the counter after each iteration. Here is my code output:

```
Old X: 1 2 3 

New X: 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 A: 4 3 2 1 4 3 2 1 4 3 2 1 4 3 2 1 4 3 2 1 Count: 0Low: 0 Mid 3 High  6 Fails

New X: 1 2 3 A: 4 3 2 1 4 3 2 1 4 3 2 1 4 3 2 1 4 3 2 1 Count: 0Low: 0 Mid 1 High  2 Fails

New X: A: 4 3 2 1 4 3 2 1 4 3 2 1 4 3 2 1 4 3 2 1 Count: 0Low: 0 Mid 0 High  0 Passes
Max repeat: 1
```

Notice that count remains `0` throughout. On the first iteration for `X^3 = [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3]`, the condition is true 5 times (`[1,1,1,2,2]` is a subsequence of A, so count should be 5, but `5 is not >= size_x * repeats(3 * 3)`, so it fails as expected. Binary search reduces to Low 0 Mid 1 High 2, so `i = repeats = 1`.

`X^1 = [1,2,3]` is a subsequence of `A`, and count should be 5 on this iteration (`[1,2,3]` plus two extra counts of 3) which is `>= size_x * repeats (3*1)`, so it should pass, and redo the search for `i = 2`. However, count remains zero and fails.

Why is count not updating? I know I need to keep it in the loop because I need it reset to 0 for each iteration, but I don't really understand why `A[j] == temp[i]` is not ever passing.

Comment: No need to cast `void`-pointers in C.

Comment: You might like to read this: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: I've read it, and tested each part. Still no good. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure you allocate space for enough `int`s here: `int * temp = (int*) malloc(size_x * sizeof(int) * repeats);`? Seeing this `for(k = 0; k < size_x; ++k){
            for(j = 0; j < repeats; ++j){
                temp[k * repeats + j] = ...` in the next lines I doubt it.

Comment: Run the program using a memory checker like Valgrind, to test all this indexing for out-of-bound access to the various arrays.

Comment: Please provide info which makes plausible that all your scanf() calls succeed. This is important because your code ignores the info available for doing that, the return value,

Comment: Please explain the role of `throwaway`, I have some rough ideas, but I do not want to guess.